# Simulating the execution of a stored procedure by multiple users

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this trigger in SQL Server

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[myTrigger]     
ON [dbo].[Data]     
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 

declare @number int

begin transaction
  select top 1 @number = NextNumber FROM settings

  Update Settings
    set NextNumber = NextNumber + 1

  UPDATE Data
    set number = @nnumber, currentDate = GetDate(), IdUser = user_id(current_user)
  FROM Data
    INNER JOIN inserted on inserted.IdData = Data.IdData

commit transaction

END
```

It works as expected but I wonder if it will work as expected when multiple users add a new row in the table `Data` at the same time?

Comment: You say it "works as expected", but you haven't listed what your expectations are - it doesn't do anything I'd expect to be asked to do (e.g. there's no `WHERE` clause on you `UPDATE` to `Data`, so it affects *every* row)

Comment: Any reason why you're not just using an `IDENTITY()` column?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've added the full code of the trigger. Anyways the question is about the users concurrency not the trigger by itself because it's working.

Comment: It's now *partially* working, unless your intention is that all rows inserted in a single statement receive a *single* number?

Comment: Yes, that's the intention. In fact, every user can insert only one row at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze this code for a minute:

```
begin transaction
```

You begin a transaction using the default `READCOMMITTED` setting.

```
select top 1 @number = NextNumber FROM settings
```

You're selecting the highest number from the `Settings` table (btw: you should by all means **add an `ORDER BY` clause** - otherwise, **no ordering** is guaranteed! You might get unexpected results here).

This operation however isn't blocking - two or more threads can read the same value of e.g. 100 at the same time - the `SELECT` only takes a shared lock for a very brief period of time, and shared locks are compatible - multiple readers can read the value simultaneously.

```
Update Settings
set NextNumber = NextNumber + 1
```

Now here, one thread gets the green light and writes back the new value - 101 in our example - to the table. The table has an `UPDATE` lock (later escalated to an exclusive lock) which is exclusive - only one thread can write at the same time

```
 UPDATE Data
 set number = @nnumber, currentDate = GetDate(), IdUser = user_id(current_user)
 FROM Data
 INNER JOIN inserted on inserted.IdData = Data.IdData
```

Same thing - that one lucky thread gets to update the `Data` table, sets number to `100` and that table's row(s) it's updating are locked until the end of the transaction.

```
 commit transaction
```

Now that lucky thread commits his transaction and is done.

**HOWEVER:** that second (and possibly third, fourth, fifth .....) thread that had read the same **original** value of 100 is still "in the loops" - now that thread #1 has completed, a second one of those threads gets to do its thing - which it does. It updates the `Settings` table correctly, to a new value of 102, and goes on doing its second update to the `Data` table, here using the "current" value of `100` that it has read into its `@number` variable, too....

In the end, you might have multiple threads that all read the same original value (100) from the `Settings` table), and each one of those will update the `Settings` table to the same "new" value (101).

This method you're using here **is not safe under load**.

Possible solutions:

1. first and foremost - the **recommended** way to do this: let the database handle this itself, by using a `INT IDENTITY` column in your table (or if you're already using SQL Server **2012** - use a `SEQUENCE` object to handle all the synchronization)
2. if you cannot do this - for whatever reasons - then **at least** make sure your code works even on a busy system! You need to e.g. use `SELECT .... WITH (UPDLOCK)` to put an (*exclusive*) `UPDATE` lock on the `Settigns` table when the first thread comes and reads the current value - that'll block all other threads from even *reading* the "current" value until the first thread has completed. Or there are alternatives like updating and assigning the old value in a single `UPDATE` operation.

Comment: NOr is it safe if a process other than the user interface, adds multipkle records at the same time. YOU may think that this will never happen, but I assure you it does. YOu get a new client or buy someonelese's user list and need to import 1,000,000 new records. Using this, they would all get the same number. You have to plan for this stuff in advance when doing datbase triggers even if you think it unlikely. Because after it happens the data integrity is so messedup it becomes impossible to fix.

Comment: @marc_s the table will always contain only one row because it's a configuration table so I don't need to use the "order by" statement. I'm currently using SQLServer 2008. I used a transaction thinking that it will solve the concurrency problem. What I need is to block the row or the table while the transaction is running. Is this possible?

Comment: @marc_s one more thing. I can't use the Identity for that row because I've to reset its value to 1 every three month

Comment: A transaction alone isn't sufficient. As I explained - the `SELECT` alone - even inside a transaction - **doesn't** sufficiently lock the value from being read and/or updated.

Comment: Um. I think, *when* the second thread gets through (and third, etc), the `UPDATE` will increment the values further (to `102`, `103`, etc) because they're just using the current column's value - but all of them will still have the same value in their `@number` variable (so the rest stands)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: ah - I see what you mean - and yes, you're right. The thread will properly update the `Settings` table - but each one of them will have the "old" current value (100) and apply that to the `Data` table ....

Comment: @marc_s in the same table I've more than one column that behave similar to this one so I can't use an Identity column to solve this :(

Answer (score 1):

> Simulating the execution of a stored procedure by multiple users

You can use two (or more) edit windows in SQL Server Management Studio and execute something like this simultaneously in each window.

```
insert into Data(ColName) values ('Value')
go 10000
```

`go 10000` will execute the batch 10000 times. Adjust that to whatever value you think is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @Mikael I was wondering too how to simulate the input of many users concurrently

Comment: Or you can use Adam Machanic's free [SQL Query Stress tool](http://www.datamanipulation.net/sqlquerystress/) to simulate any number of concurrent clients executing some queries